# Change Cursor when Hovering Over Part of Frame TKinter

Tags: python, binding, tkinter, cursor

How can you make the cursor change when you hover over a certain part of a frame? I am trying to make it so there is a background image and when someone hovers over a certain part that, if clicked on, will make the frame change, the cursor will change to signal that interaction will occur if they click.

```
class Map(Frame):
    def __init__(self, master, controller, *args, **kwargs):
        Frame.__init__(self, master)
        self.controller = controller
        #keep player data stored at all times
        self.player = Player.Player()
        # define map gui here
        #repack this frame so binding included
        self.map_picture = PhotoImage(file=r"images/rsz_archipelago.gif")
        self.image = Label(self, image=self.map_picture)
        self.image.bind("<Button-1>", self.check_for_spot)
        self.image.grid(row=0, column=0, columnspan=40, rowspan=40)

        self.places = {MapRectange(420,490,175, 205):Hydra_Level}


    def check_for_spot(self, event):
        x1, y1 = event.x, event.y
        pt = Point(x1,y1)
        print("X: " + str(x1) + "  Y: " + str(y1))
        for place, level in self.places.iteritems():
            if place.point_is_in(pt):
                self.controller.show(level, self)
                break
```

Comment: so, you would like the cursor to change when it is in the frame, or/and the image to change after clicking over an image in a frame?

Comment: I want to be able to tell the cursor to change when it enters certain coordinates in the frame

Comment: you can specify a range, and if you are capturing the cursor coordinates, indicate it to change if it has certain coordinate ranges

Comment: how do you capture cursor coordinates, like every millisecond?

Comment: view below answer, let me know if you have further questions. cheers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get your cursor coordinates:

```
import Tkinter as tk
from Tkinter import Frame
root = tk.Tk()
frame1 = Frame(root, bg='blue',width='100px', height='100px')
frame1.pack()

def motion(event):
    x, y = event.x, event.y
    print('{}, {}'.format(x, y))


frame1.bind('<Motion>', motion)
root.mainloop()
```

you will see in your console, the coordinates while you move the cursor, afterwards, you can define ranges and have the cursor change based or the image... 
please refer to http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/ there is excellent documentation on pythons Tkinter.

Answer (score 0):

Use **cursor** attrubute like this:

```
YourFrame.cursor = pencil
```

See: http://infohost.nmt.edu/tcc/help/pubs/tkinter/web/cursors.html
http://infohost.nmt.edu/tcc/help/pubs/tkinter/web/frame.html